# call a function using a inputbox with a checkbox with an if/else statement

Tags: excel, vba

So i have 2 functions, I want an inputbox that also has a checkbox so I can run an if/else statement.

I've tried using userforms but i don't quite understand how to get them working right.

I want to use something like

```
If checkbox = True
   Call GetSubFiles
else 
   call GetAllFiles
end if
```

(dont even know if that will work its psuedo code)

the 2 functions i want to call are

```
Sub GetAllFiles()


Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim Path As Variant

Path = InputBox("Enter filepath")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path)

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

With Range("A1", "H1")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(12, 2, 120)
    .Value = "Table of Contents"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 3
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

Range("A1").Value = "Directory"
Range("B1").Value = "File Name"
Range("C1").Value = "Size KB"
Range("D1").Value = "Date Created"
Range("E1").Value = "Date Last Modified"
Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
Range("G1").Value = "Path Length"
Range("H1").Value = "File Type"

Call GetFileDetails(objFolder)

End Sub
```

If the checkbox is not clicked

and

```
Sub GetSubFiles()

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

With Range("A1", "H1")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(12, 2, 120)
    .Value = "Table of Contents"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Size = .Font.Size + 3
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End With

Range("A1").Value = "Directory"
Range("B1").Value = "File Name"
Range("C1").Value = "Size KB"
Range("D1").Value = "Date Created"
Range("E1").Value = "Date Last Modified"
Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
Range("G1").Value = "Path Length"
Range("H1").Value = "File Type"

Call listSubFiles

End Sub
```

if the checkbox is clicked

this input box needs to be able to take a string for the filepath
and a true or false checkbox to decide if it must list the contents of the subfolder or just the subfolder itself

Comment: what is the problem or error?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stacked?

Comment: ive tried using the userforms for excel and 2 input boxes where one has to litterally be a 1/0 to run the if else statement i want a more streamline approach